# Proof of student loan payoff

Tags: student-loan

I paid off my student loan (which was held by Nelnet).  I expected a big "congratulations" email with some form that proved I'd paid the loan off.  Maybe that will still come in the post.  Is there anything in particular I should print off of their website, as proof that I paid the loan off?

Comment: Does it say anywhere on your statement that the balance is 0?

Comment: It says it on the main page.  I haven't gotten a monthly statement yet; I just paid it off.

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: How did you pay? Presumably you didn't pay with cash, so there should be a record of your payment through your bank or whatever you used.

Comment: @Acccumulation - precious metals sent through a courier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the monthly statement would have this information.  The year-end statement detailing interest paid should show your final balance as well.  Either of these should provide sufficient proof.

Comment: I see it's been two months since you posted this; did you get either of these?

Comment: I took the advice in the comments and saved the last statement (with a '0' balance).  Finally a letter did come that stated the loan was paid off - it just took awhile.